# Char cannot be converted to boolean?

Tags: java, char, boolean

This is my first project I've done so I know there are a lot of mistakes. I'm trying to create a calculator using nested if else statements. The only error I'm getting is that in the if statements I get that I can't go from char to boolean. I don't know why it thinks I'm trying to change to boolean but I', guessing the " = A " etc probably makes it think that? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //main class
    char result = 0; //define and declare variables
    double firstNumber = 0;
    double secondNumber = 0;
    double answer = 0;

    System.out.println("Calculator Program\n"); //Text for user
    System.out.println("Choose how to proceed:\n");
    System.out.println("A. Add\n");
    System.out.println("B. Subtract\n");
    System.out.println("C. Multiply\n");
    System.out.println("D. Divide\n");

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); //create new Scanner
    result = userInput.next().charAt(0); //Take only the first letter entered

    if (result = A){

        System.out.println("Please enter the first number: ");
            firstNumber = userInput.nextDouble(); //redefine first number
                userInput.next(); //clears line
        System.out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
            secondNumber = userInput.nextDouble(); //redefine second number 
                userInput.next(); //clears line

        answer = firstNumber + secondNumber; //algorithim 
        System.out.println("Answer: " + firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " = " + answer);//print answer

                   }

            else if ( result = B){
                   System.out.println("Please enter the first number: ");
                    firstNumber = userInput.nextDouble(); //redefine first number
                        userInput.next(); //clears line
                System.out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
                    secondNumber = userInput.nextDouble(); //redefine second number 
                        userInput.next(); //clears line

                answer = firstNumber - secondNumber; //algorithim 
                System.out.println("Answer: " + firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + " = " + answer);//print answer

                                }

                    else if ( result = C){
                          System.out.println("Please enter the first number: ");
                           firstNumber = userInput.nextDouble(); //redefine first number
                               userInput.next(); //clears line
                       System.out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
                           secondNumber = userInput.nextDouble(); //redefine second number 
                               userInput.next(); //clears line

                       answer = firstNumber * secondNumber; //algorithim 
                       System.out.println("Answer: " + firstNumber + " * " + secondNumber + " = " + answer);//print answer
                                           }

                            else if ( result = D){
                              System.out.println("Please enter the first number: ");
                             firstNumber = userInput.nextDouble(); //redefine first number
                                 userInput.next(); //clears line
                         System.out.println("Please enter the second number: ");
                             secondNumber = userInput.nextDouble(); //redefine second number 
                                 userInput.next(); //clears line

                         answer = firstNumber / secondNumber; //algorithim 
                         System.out.println("Answer: " + firstNumber + " / " + secondNumber + " = " + answer);//print answer 
                                      }



}
```

}

Comment: assignment vs. equality. (`=` vs. `==`) And character literals are surrounded by single quotes (`'A'`).

Comment: Correct: the type of an assignment expression is the type of the variable assigned to. So the expression `aChar = '?'` is typed as a `char`, but `if` only accepts a `boolean`-typed expression. Then the question is "Why does = not be have as expected?", for which there is plenty of existing tutorials/books/references :)

Answer (score 1):

`char` cannot be converted to `boolean`.

Seems like you want to make checks. You can do something like,

```
String sum = "0+3";

boolean isPlus = (sum.charAt(1) == '+');
```

`isPlus` will now hold true since the character at index 1 of `sum` is '+'

Comment: Or he's using the assignment operator in an `if` statement.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yep. I included that in my answer also, showing how == is generating the boolean value

Answer (score 0):

in the if block you are assigning A to the result.
you should do if(result == 'A')//'A' not A

Answer (score 0):

You check like this:

```
if (result == 'A')
```

change `A` to `'A'` and `=` to `==`

Answer (score 0):

In order to match character your need to change your if statement to if(result == 'A') instead of if(result == A)

The following code will give you more clarity:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class checkBoolToChar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char a  = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = in.next().charAt(0);

        if(a ==  'A'){
            System.out.println("Match ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write the condition as

```
    if(result = A)
```

it is actually assigning the value A to result variable. Now, since A is not written in quotes, it assumes A to be a variable but since it is not declared anywhere in the program, it assumes it to be a boolean value. But the data type of result is char. Hence it is giving you the data type mismatch error. If you write it as

```
    if(result == "A")
```

It will check if the letter is A and the error will be removed.